# ssh_config Host * overrides earlier host

Tags: ssh, osx, ssh-config

Im trying to make my .ssh/config support different ssh keys for the same host so that I can commit to bitbucket as either my personal or work user, and other ssh stuff still uses my work user.

My config file looks like this:

```
Host bitbucket-personal
 HostName bitbucket.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
 IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

when I `ssh bitbucket-personal` it is using the `~/.ssh/work` key which is not what I'm expecting (see below docs, it should use the first matching IdentityFile). But all the other params are correctly referenced (eg git@bitbucket.com). If I remove the Host * section it uses the correct key.

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing I have missunderstood how the precedence here works.

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. The configuration files contain sections separated by “Host” specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification. The matched host name is the one given on the command line.
>
> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

Full verbose trace below:

```
luke$ ssh -v bitbucket-personal
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/luke/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/luke/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket-personal
debug1: /Users/luke/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/luke/.ssh/luke type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/luke/.ssh/luke-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/luke/.ssh/luke-cx type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/luke/.ssh/luke-cx-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.1.15-49a70a8 app-154
debug1: no match: conker_1.1.15-49a70a8 app-154
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:qqq
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/luke/.ssh/known_hosts:52
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:qqqq /Users/luke/.ssh/luke-cx
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.com ([18.205.93.3]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_NZ.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
logged in as lukemcgregor-x.
```

Comment: Add `-v` when you run `ssh` and look at the output for more information.

Comment: Agree. Most likely `ssh` _is_ trying your `~/.ssh/personal` key, but somehow it's not working. In this scenario, `ssh` tries the next match (here, your `~/.ssh/work` key).

Comment: Your understanding of precedence among directives is right, but note that the `IdentityFile` directive differs from others in that it can be supplied many times: the keys in matching directives are tried in sequence (see paragraph `IdentityFile` in `man ssh_config`).

Comment: Ive had a bit of a look through the verbose output. I can see it using the ~/.ssh/work key but it never tries the personal one, it jump straight to `Offering public key: .../.ssh/work`

Comment: It says it will use the identities in sequence, but if I switch the keys around I get the one I would expect (eg my work one). It's like its somehow taking precedence no matter the order in the file.

Comment: Please, provide the complete log and try to reproduce the issue with this minimal configuration (I assume you might have more things in there). With this sparse information, it is not possible to answer your question.

Comment: And check your `~/.ssh/personal` key file's permissions. As stated in the `FILES` section of `man ssh`, keys accessible to others are "simply ignore"d. On Linux + OpenSSH_7.9p1 I get a warning if I try a key with wrong permissions set, but it may not be the same on other implementations.

Comment: @Jakuje ive added the full verbose log as requested. Keys named slightly different to the question but otherwise the config is identical.

Comment: In my particular case adding `IdentityAgent none` besides the `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal` part did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this same issue recently.  The SSH Host config allows for an exclusion, so this would do what you want (use one identity file every except for the bitbucket.com alias)

```
Host bitbucket-personal
 HostName bitbucket.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
 IdentitiesOnly yes

Host * !bitbucket-personal
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

The man page for ssh_config (for some version) says that the first value set is used, which seems to imply that the original config should work.  But I found that this exclusion was necessary (for ssh on OSX, ssh -V `OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`)

Comment: Thank you! Can confirm this on macOS 12.1

Comment: I can't upgrade to Monterrey yet, so I cannot.  Monterrey has `OpenSSH_8.6` but my GUESS would be it works the same.  Why not just try?

Comment: * I can confirm this answer solves the issue on macOS 12.1!

Comment: Thanks, but wtf. I find this rather distasteful.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ssh-agent or something like that to cache your decrypted private keys, which might change the order in which the keys are offered. This would be visible in more verbose log level (with multiple `-v`).

Also the `IdentitiesOnly` option has a slightly different meaning than you might assume -- it will limit the keys that will be offered to the server, but does not limit it to the one preceding the option. It is mostly used to avoid offering identities in default location loaded automatically (`~/.ssh/id_{rsa,dsa,ecdsa,ed25519}`).

The `IdentitiyFile` option is also slightly different than you assume. Is allowed to be specified multiple times (see the manual page) so also the one in `Match *` section will be used.

If you want to use some key by default and other only for this specific host, move the "default" one to the default location `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and remove it from the configuration file. It should solve your problems.